# rampToVideoZoomFactor doesn't work on iPhone 7

Tags: camera, zooming, ios10

I used `rampToVideoZoomFactor` to zoom-out/zoom-in back camera, but now it's not working on iPhone 7+.

I'm getting the AVCaptureDevice with this code:

```
let doubleCamDevice = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession.init(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDuoCamera], mediaType: nil, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back).devices.first
```

What is the problem with that?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Please provide specific details.

Comment: it wasn't zooming in and out. I set the zoom with:  doubleCamDevice.rampToVideoZoomFactor(zoom, withRate: rateFloat)